# Problemas con funcion Click y Keydown

Tags: html, jquery

mi problema es que solo funciona si le hago click al boton y si coloco el keydown entonces toca hacer tab encima del boton y darle enter. quiero que funcione dandole click al boton enviar y dando enter en el campo como los chats. alguna idea de como hacerlo.

```
<form id="mensajeform">
          <input type="text" id="nick" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["nombres"];?>" hidden>
          <input id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribir un mensaje aqui" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate col s11">
          <div id="enviar"  style="background-color:  transparent;border:  transparent;"><img src="views/imagen/enviar.png"></div>
          </form>



$("#enviar").click(function(){

    nick = $("#nick").val();
    mensaje = $("#mensaje").val();

    console.log(nick,mensaje);

    });
```

Comment: el submit me recarga el dom y no quiero eso.

Comment: usa el evento click()  como el usuario que comento abajo lo comenta, para agregar mas informacion, lee esto :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea una función con la funcionalidad para enviar e invócala tanto desde el evento `click` del botón como desde el `keydown` de la caja de texto si la tecla pulsada es Enter:

```js
function enviar(){
  nick = $("#nick").val();
  mensaje = $("#mensaje").val();

  console.log(nick,mensaje);
}

$(function(){
  $('#enviar').click(enviar);
  $('#mensaje').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') enviar();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mensajeform">
          <input type="text" id="nick" value="Nick_Usuario" hidden>
          <input id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribir un mensaje aqui" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate col s11">
          <div id="enviar"  style="background-color:  transparent;border:  transparent;"><img src="views/imagen/enviar.png"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: muy buen aporte, otra pregunta por que colocas 13 ?

Comment: Cierto @Marcos. Corregido en la respuesta.